# Spring Java 8 project, REST DOCS, Failed to create directory

Tags: java, spring, rest, documentation, circleci

I am trying my project to pass the test. In my test classes I am creating rest docs .adoc snippets files that are generated and stored in target folder. In circle ci I am not able to store them. Below you can see config.yml, test class and error I got in circle ci. It does not occur on my local computer.

config.yml -> https://github.com/WojciechWeg/tiny-bank/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml

test (line 135) -> https://github.com/WojciechWeg/tiny-bank/blob/master/src/test/java/com/tinybank/tinybankapi/controllers/CustomerControllerTest.java

error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create directory ‘/api/customers-get’
at com.tinybank.tinybankapi.controllers.CustomerControllerTest.getCustomer(CustomerControllerTest.java:135)
```